# How to lock files from Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

I want to find lock files and lock-unlock these files from Team Foundation Server. How can I do that?

Comment: The title and body of this question seem to be asking different things.

Answer (score 3):

If you Check out a file by right clicking on it in Source Control Explorer and selecting Check Out For Edit, you should get three options under Lock Type:

- **Unchanged:** This allows other users to modify the file and save the changes back to TFS before you have finished with it.
- **Check Out:** This completely locks the file so that no one else can modify it.
- **Check In:** This allows other people to modify the file, but prevents them from saving the changes back to TFS until you have finished with the file.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Source Control Explorer, right-click the branch you want to check, find in source control, and then choose status. There you have the option to find checked-out files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Status Sidekicks tool from [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) toolset to find out all the files which has been locked out. You can unlock them using same tool.

Answer (score 0):

See:

- [Lock and Unlock Folders or Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181420.aspx)
- [Lock Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47b0c7w9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)